# Is it possible to use Felix Dependency Manager in an Eclipse Plugin?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, osgi, apache-felix

I coded a bundle that uses [Apache Felix Dependency management](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-dependency-manager.html).  It's Activator extends
[DependencyActivatorBase](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/apache/felix/org.apache.felix.dependencymanager/3.0.0/org.apache.felix.dependencymanager-3.0.0-sources.jar!/org/apache/felix/dm/DependencyActivatorBase.java?format=ok).  But Plugin my plugin activator extends [AbstractUIPlugin](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2Fplugin%2FAbstractUIPlugin.html).  How can I get services from the felix dependency manager from within the eclipse plugin?

[DependencyManager](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/apache/felix/org.apache.felix.dependencymanager/3.0.0/org.apache.felix.dependencymanager-3.0.0-sources.jar!/org/apache/felix/dm/DependencyManager.java?format=ok) has a getDepenencyManagers method but it is a list, not sure how I would know the right manager in the list.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use Dependency Manager in any OSGi framework, including Equinox (on which Eclipse is based).

Why does your bundle activator **need** to extend `AbstractUIPlugin`?? Are you actually using `AbstractUIPlugin,` or was this just generated for you because you used Eclipse PDE to generate the initial code? The project templates in PDE are basically junk, most bundles do not need activators at all, and very very few really need to extend `AbstractUIPlugin`.

So, just change your activator to extend `DependencyActivatorBase` instead of `AbstractUIPlugin`.

Comment: Exactly right, I extended from PDE samples.  I guess I just assumed AbstractUIPlugin was a necessary component to adding any UI elements in my plugin.  Can you briefly say what the purpose of AbstractUIPlugin is?

Comment: `AbstractUIPlugin` gives slightly easier access to things like preferences and the image registry. The JavaDoc for the class has full details. However none of these things are difficult to access... if you need them then just read the code of `AbstractUIPlugin` and follow the same pattern.

Answer (score 2):

The DependencyActivatorBase class is just a base class that is there for your convenience. If, for some reason, you cannot use it (like, arguably, in your case), you can always instantiate an instance of DependencyManager yourself from your own class. All it needs is a reference to the BundleContext (which you can get from the start() method of BundleActivator, assuming you do implement that yourself). Then just do something like this:

```
DependencyManager dm = new DependencyManager(bundleContext);
dm.add(dm.createComponent()
  .setImplementation(YourComponent.class)
  .add(dm.createServiceDependency()
    .setService(LogService.class)
  )
);
```

Comment: I was thinking of DependencyManager like Spring's ApplicationContext.  So, unlike Spring's ApplicationContext, it is OK to have more than one  DependencyManager?  I'm assuming there is no need for one DependencyManager since it is merely interacting the services maintained by the OSGI container rather than maintaining them in its own context?

Comment: That is perfectly fine. You should have at least one DependencyManager for each bundle, but that's because it uses the BundleContext you pass in the constructor and that should not be shared amongst bundles. You can use more than one DependencyManager per bundle if you want. It is just an instance that holds the declarative data about components and their dependencies.